# gradle build failed in eclipse oxygen in spring boot application

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

[gradle build failed in eclipse oxygen ide. I am new to the gradle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXmeS.png)

Comment: Can you explain in more details and post your stack trace.

Comment: Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip'.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'spring-boot-gradle'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:.I am getting the above error message.

Comment: It looks like network problem. Could you include stack trace in question and  not as comment.